# Telegram Bot API with console apps

Tags: c#, console-application, telegram-bot

I just started to play with Telegram Bot API. Everything is work fine except for console apps..`

```
        var bot = new TelegramBotClient("token");
        bot.SendTextMessageAsync("group_id", "1" + ":Something not right!", false, false);
```

I use above code to implement Telegram Bot on window service and winforms. So can anyone guide me to make this work on console apps?

Comment: so it work already with windows service and winforms? if you want to implement it as console application you should be able to use pretty the same code as you used before. To be able to help you, you must give further information about the code and what exactly is not working

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [examples](https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot.examples).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519495/how-to-solve-disturbance-in-my-bot-in-c

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, it didn't work until a put a `Console.Read()` at the end of my app.

Trying to figure out why this happen, but it should be something with the app has to wait for the async answer.